# Navigation Drawer null in Android 6

Tags: android

I need if possible help on my app navigation drawer.

From Google docs I've implemented a google map application with a NavDrawer.
All it's ok on android 4 and 5.
The problem is on Android 6.
I face this error:
**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(int)' on a null object reference**

In build gradle I have:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23 **(If i switch to targetSdkVersion 17 all is ok also in Android 6)**.
```

and in dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
```

Here is my main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- The main content view -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_xcv"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/activity_mappa_partenza" />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            layout="@layout/navdrawer_header" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="@drawable/sfondo_drawer"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
        <!--android:background="#111"-->

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            layout="@layout/navdrawer_barrasotto" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Someone can tell me what i'm doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Just operating on a hunch here, but with Android 6.0 came the NavigationView: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html

Try to wrap your drawerlayout in a NavigationView and make the calls to opendrawer on that, instead.

Comment: Thanks..I wonder what happen for the compatibility with older version of Android...in this scenario ?...